# What events should be set for SQL profiler 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I want to use SQL pro-filer 2008 for getting the exact query that is fired against the database.
For the SQL pro-filer what events should be set in order to get the exact SQL query?

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity, you can use the TSQL_Replay template.

EDIT:
SQL:StmtStarting, SQL:BatchStarting, SP:StmtStarting, SP:RPCStarting.
You can choose *Completed events (for example, SQL:StmtCompleted) if you want to see the duration of statement.

Comment: But I want to use Anjlab Sql Profiler so can you tell me exactly whet events I should set because Currently I am not getting the query just some binary code is generated.